# Handling incoming GET requests to replace form input in Javascript web application

Tags: javascript, jquery, http, http-get

Edit: Answer I was looking for is [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript). I wasn't familiar with the term 'query string' so didn't have a good sense of what to look for.

I have a simple web application that takes search criteria in a web form and produces visualizations with data returned from a DB from those criteria. For the sake of this example, let's say the search form takes a searchString and a date, and returns some arbitrary array of data that is displayed in the UI.

I would like to add GET request handling such that, if given a get request such as:

`http://myApp.com/?searchstring="MySearch"&date="1-1-1990"`

I can use that input as if it was entered in the form and the "submit" button was clicked. However I am not sure how to build this functionality on the JavaScript end. My server already features a simple API which the JS frontend uses to communicate with a backend, however this only returns JSON which is interpreted by the UI.

Is there a simple way to create an event handler for GET requests and parse out the data contained? It seems similar to the API I use, but I am not sure how to run this on the client side or attach it to some sort of event handler.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't sure what terms to look for, I guess 'query string' is what I wanted. Is the way to deal with event handling to check the query string on the onLoad event, and if it isn't empty, call my handler method?

Comment: yes, on page load just run the code and extract variables from query string.